# cURL from command-line get response + callback

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, curl, libcurl

Currently I use this:

```
curl -F 'access_token=token' https://somewebsite.com/oauth/like/id
```

Response I receive is:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":null}
```

However, I'm sending many requests at the same time, so I don't know who's response that is. I would like to get a response to something like

```
{'123456': {"meta":{"code":200},"data":null} }
```

Where 123456 is some id I send with the request. A similar solution would be really appreciated. I've done this with PHP, however I want this to work through command-line.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are pinging a server you should use a callback for when the response is called.

In the callback you should know what request it was from.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, how can I use that?